# How much of JavaScript stops working when an errors occur in some line in the browser?

Tags: javascript, browser

JS in a web page is composed of multiple  tags that load files and execute them or execute the code directly in case of inline  tags. Now assuming one of them stops executing on some particular line due to an error, do the other scripts also stop? In other words, the browser action of suspending the interpreting and execution of a piece of code when an error occurs is done on a  tag level or the global level?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In other words, the browser action of suspending the interpreting and execution of a piece of code when an error occurs is done on a tag level or the global level?

That depends.

**Syntax errors** mean the entire script loaded by the given `script` tag will fail to work, because the code cannot be parsed.

**Runtime errors** only mean that whatever was happening when the error occurred will have terminated (if it didn't handle the error). But only the job that was actively running when the error occurred is terminated; other code loaded by that same `script` tag will continue to work.

Example: This code has a syntax error in it, and so none of the code works:

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Clicked");
}, false);

// This is the syntax error:
if
```

```html
Clicking this button doesn't do anything:
<br><input type="button" id="btn" value="Click me">
```

Whereas this has a *runtime* error between hooking up the first event handler and hooking up the second. As a consequence, the second handler is never hooked up, but the first continues to work:

```js
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Button 1 clicked");
}, false);

// This is the runtime error:
null.foo();

document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Button 2 clicked");
}, false);
```

```html
<div>Clicking this button works:</div>
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Button 1">

<div>Clicking this button doesn't do anything:</div>
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Button 2">
```

In both cases, that only affects the code loaded by that `script` element, though, because running that is a job; running the content of any subsequent `script` element is a new job. So the *first* and *third* buttons here work, but the second doesn't, because the third is hooked up by a separate job:

```html
<div>Clicking this button works:</div>
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Button 1">

<div>Clicking this button doesn't do anything:</div>
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Button 2">

<div>Clicking this button works:</div>
<input type="button" id="btn3" value="Button 3">

<script>
// First job
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Button 1 clicked");
}, false);

// This is the runtime error:
null.foo();

document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Button 2 clicked");
}, false);
</script>

<script>
// Second job
document.getElementById("btn3").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Button 3 clicked");
}, false);
</script>
```

Of course, if that subsequent `script` relied on something in the earlier `script` that didn't work, well, it's not going to work correctly — but the code will (try to) run.

Comment: In other words anything happening in one process tick (execution of one block of synchronous code) would either complete or fail? Is that what you mean when saying task?

Comment: @vijayant - Mostly, yes. A job/task (job is the JS term, task is the HTML/browser term) is a unit of work that the code does. There's a job that gets queued to run the main code in a `script`, but that code can set things up so other jobs (event handler callbacks, timer callbacks, asynchronous completions) queue subsequent jobs. A job *runs to completion*, whether that completion is normal termination or an error termination. An error in one job doesn't prevent other jobs from running (unless, of course, they rely on the previous job's result).